# Open iTerm and execute some commands automatically

Tags: automator, iterm, alfred

I need to open some terminal sessions via iTerm 2 and execute commands on each terminal (e.g. rails s ; rails c)

How to do it via automator or alfred?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with an Alfred Worflow (you need the [Powerpack](http://www.alfredapp.com/powerpack/)).

First create a `Blank Workflow` and fill the data:

[image]

Use the plus symbol in the right cornet to add `Trigger → Hotkey` action. Define your prefered hotkey and save it.

[image]

Add `Actions → Run script`. Use `/usr/bin/osascript` as language. Paste the following script and save it. Change `ls -l` to whatever command you want to execute.

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set the clipboard to "ls -l"
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

[image]

Connect the two actions and you will be ready.

[image]

[image]

Type your hotkey and it will open iTerm and execute your command.